# Using Vim plugins in IntelliJ through IdeaVim

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

Is there a way I can use Vim plugins in IntelliJ through IdeaVim? In this case I am looking for a way to use the easymotion Vim plugin.

Comment: No you can't use any Vim plugin because Vim emulation layers usually don't have vimscript or the language bindings that make plugins like easymotion work. Vrapper (for Eclipse) includes a re-implementation of Surround, for example, but doesn't provide any way to write/use a vimscript-based plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `acejump` plugin or `emacsIDEAs` (Don't be scared by its name. It just introduces ace-jump features) plugin along with the `IdeaVim` plug.

Comment: Thanks, Acejump suits my need.

Answer (score 0):

[KJump](https://github.com/a690700752/KJump) is a clone of the Vim EasyMotion plugin designed to integrate with IdeaVim. (But it also works standalone.)